# Pandas shifting uneven timeseries data

Tags: pandas, shift

I have some irregularly stamped time series data, with timestamps and the observations at every timestamp, in pandas. Irregular basically means that the timestamps are uneven, for instance the gap between two successive timestamps is not even.

For instance the data may look like

```
    Timestamp     Property
    0                100
    1                200
    4                300
    6                400
    6                401
    7                500
    14               506
    24               550
           .....
    59               700
    61               750
    64               800
```

Here the timestamp is say seconds elapsed since a chose origin time. As you can see we could have data at the same timestamp, 6 secs in this case. Basically the timestamps are strictly different, just that second resolution cannot measure the change.

Now I need to shift the timeseries data ahead, say I want to shift the entire data by 60 secs, or a minute. So the target output is

```
  Timestamp     Property
    0                750
    1                800
```

So the 0 point got matched to the 61 point and the 1 point got matched to the 64 point.

Now I can do this by writing something dirty, but I am looking to use as much as possible any inbuilt pandas feature. If the timeseries were regular, or evenly gapped, I could've just used the shift() function. But the fact that the series is uneven makes it a bit tricky. Any ideas from Pandas experts would be welcome. I feel that this would be a commonly encountered problem. Many thanks!

Comment: First question: you say that the timestamps are all strictly different but a resolution of one second produces duplicates. In that case, why are you storing it with that resolution? Is your data stored at a resolution of one second or do you have access to the timestamps with their original resolution?

Comment: Second question: Can you clarify your desired behavior a bit? In your example data, if the Timestamp of 1 matches to the value of Timestamp 64, where do you want Timestamp 4 to map to? Should it also map to Timestamp 64? In other words, for Timestamp `t`, should it always match `s` where `s` is the smallest timestamp such that `s > t+60`? Are duplicate matches okay?

Comment: Thanks for the note exp1orer, yes the data is stored at a second resolution, its like a restriction that I dont have control over. Yes the time stamp should match to s such that s is smallest wherein s > t+60. Duplicate matches can happen and the are ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: added a second, more elegant, way to do it. I don't know what will happen if you had a timestamp at 1 and two timestamps of 61. I think it will choose the first 61 timestamp but not sure.

```
new_stamps = pd.Series(range(df['Timestamp'].max()+1))
shifted = pd.DataFrame(new_stamps)
shifted.columns = ['Timestamp']

merged = pd.merge(df,shifted,on='Timestamp',how='outer')
merged['Timestamp'] = merged['Timestamp'] - 60
merged = merged.sort(columns = 'Timestamp').bfill()

results = pd.merge(df,merged, on = 'Timestamp')
```

---

[Original Post]
I can't think of an inbuilt or elegant way to do this. Posting this in case it's more elegant than your "something dirty", which is I guess unlikely. How about:

```
lookup_dict = {}

def assigner(row):
    lookup_dict[row['Timestamp']] = row['Property']

df.apply(assigner, axis=1)
sorted_keys = sorted(lookup_dict.keys)
df['Property_Shifted'] = None

def get_shifted_property(row,shift_amt):
    for i in sorted_keys:
        if i >= row['Timestamp'] + shift_amt:
            row['Property_Shifted'] = lookup_dict[i]
    return row

df = df.apply(get_shifted_property, shift_amt=60, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes I had something like this in mind also :). Is there any way we can avoid a for look explicitly.

Comment: Oh, this totally would not work, because you would have duplicate keys in the dictionary. Which brings up the question, what would you want to happen if say you have two rows with Timestamp = 61. Which of them should Timestamp 1 match to?

Comment: If that is the case, then it will just match to the first one right as you mention?

Comment: One more dumb question exp1orer, due to my limited understanding of the pandas library. Here it seems that we were referring the column with timestamps explicitly the name, 'Timestamp'. What I actually have is an indexed data frame with index = timestamp. Do I have to name the column also? How do I port this to the case in which I don't have the column names?

Comment: You can just `df.reset_index(inplace=True)`, and then rename the column to 'Timestamp' and this should still work.